# Update UI using partial view in response of Task Run (Async)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, async-await, task

I am working on MVC C# Razor Framework 4.6.

I have static method `ExportManager.ExportExcelCannedReportPPR` wrapped up in `Task.Run` for long running report. This method returns `boolean` value and based on that I am refreshing partial view (`_NotificationPanel`).

```
public ActionResult ExportCannedReport(string cannedReportKey, string cannedReportName)
{            
    string memberKeys = _curUser.SecurityInfo.AccessibleFacilities_MemberKeys; //ToDo: Make sure this is fine or need to pass just self member?
    string memberIds = _curUser.SecurityInfo.AccessibleFacilities_MemberIDs; //ToDo: Make sure this is fine or need to pass just self member?
    string curMemberNameFormatted = _curUser.FacilityInfo.FacilityName.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    string cannedReportNameFormatted = cannedReportName.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    string fileName = string.Concat(cannedReportNameFormatted, "_", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), "_", curMemberNameFormatted);
    //ToDo: Make sure below getting userId is correct
    string userId = ((_curUser.IsECRIStaff.HasValue && _curUser.IsECRIStaff.Value) ? _curUser.MembersiteUsername : _curUser.PGUserName);

    var returnTask = Task.Run<bool>(() => ExportManager.ExportExcelCannedReportPPR(cannedReportKey, cannedReportName, fileName, memberIds, userId));
    returnTask.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
    {
        if (antecedent.Result == true)
        {
            return PartialView("_NotificationPanel", "New file(s) added in 'Download Manager'.");
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("_NotificationPanel", "An error occurred while generating the report.");
        }
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

    return PartialView("_NotificationPanel", "");
}
```

Now issue is that UI could not get refresh even though `_NotificationPanel` in `ContinueWith` get executed.

Comment: What do you really expect to happen with that code?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that once you return from it - that request is done. You cannot return from it multiple times for a single request. The request and response are a 1-to-1. You need to use `async` and `await` here, such that when the export is done then and only then return a result.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExportCannedReport(string cannedReportKey, 
                                                   string cannedReportName)
{            
    // Omitted for brevity...

    var result = 
        await Task.Run<bool>(() => 
            ExportManager.ExportExcelCannedReportPPR(cannedReportKey, 
                                                     cannedReportName, 
                                                     fileName, 
                                                     memberIds, 
                                                     userId));

    return PartialView("_NotificationPanel", 
        result 
            ? "New file(s) added in 'Download Manager'."
            : "An error occurred while generating the report.");
}
```

You need to make the method `Task` returning such that it is "awaitable". Then you mark the method as `async` which enables the `await` keyword. Finally, you're ready to execute the long running task and from the result correctly determine and return the desired partial view update.

**Update**

Alternatively, you could utilize an **AJAX** call on the client and update once the server responds. For details on that specifically checkout [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks David. Actually this holds the user to access other functionality. User can access other functionality once execution of Task.Run finish so at the end it will be sync method. Can you please provide your suggestion.